# Can't access any settings for Android project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an existing project that I created with Android Studio.  I have gotten away without needing to change the project structure settings so far, but now I need to add the Facebook SDK and need to add a new module.  Does anyone know why I can't see any other options in my project structure?  I have tried rebuilding my project, but no luck.  BTW, I'm on v0.2.9.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Android Studio has moved things around a bit.  There are numerous other posts out there about this, but settings like "module settings" and others are now just in the context menu of your project.

Also consider using your "settings.gradle" to reference local modules if needed.  When you sync your project, it will automatically set up your module settings for you.